# Sphinx: "WARNING: py:class reference target not found" for class variable

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have two files, `foo.py` and `bar.py`.

`foo.py` contains:

```
import bar


class B():
    a = bar.A
```

`bar.py` contains:

```
class A():
    pass
```

I am generating documentation for these in `docs/index.rst` via:

```
.. automodule:: bar
   :members:
   :undoc-members:

.. automodule:: foo
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
```

Now, when I run `build html` with the nit-picky flag (`-n`), I get the following, with a warning, `WARNING: py:class reference target not found: A`:

```
(env)bash-3.2$ make html
sphinx-build -b html -d _build/doctrees  -n . _build/html
Running Sphinx v1.2.3
loading pickled environment... done
building [html]: targets for 1 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 0 added, 1 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] index
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [100%] index
/Users/caesarbautista/Desktop/test_docs/docs/index.rst:12: WARNING: py:class reference target not found: A
writing additional files... genindex py-modindex search
copying static files... done
copying extra files... done
dumping search index... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded, 1 warning.

Build finished. The HTML pages are in _build/html.
```

How can I fix this warning?

So far I've tried searching Google and the documentation with no luck. It also has nothing to do with with how `A` is imported. I've tried `from bar import A` with no success. The error message is awfully opaque.

A copy of the test project I set up can be found [here](https://github.com/Ceasar/sandbox-sphinx).

Comment: Interesting, I didn't get that warning when I tried it from your source code. Which version of Sphinx did you use? I used v1.3.1.

Comment: I've got the same problem when using Sphix v1.3.1 ``py:obj reference target not found (str|integer)``

Comment: Was this problem resolved? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

In your code you had

```
class B():
    a = bar.A
```

You must use an instantiation instead of a class alias.
The warning just disappear when I replace `a = bar.A` with `a = bar.A()`

Comment: I don't think this is the way to go. `a = bar.A` and `a = bar.A()` are both perfectly valid Python statements to include at that point in the code, with different meanings, and you shouldn't have to change from one to the other just to get the documentation to work because it will affect the functionality of your program. (It is certainly possible that it's a typo, but that's a separate matter from the question being asked.)